# react native webview not working in android 10+

Tags: android, react-native

react native webview not working in android 10 or higher. It works fine in dev mode but shows just a white screen in production mode.

```
<WebView
  ref={webView}
  javaScriptEnabled
  injectedJavaScript={initialJs}
  source={{
    uri: "http://www.example.com",
  }}
  onMessage={(event) => {
    console.log(event);
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have something to do with clearTextTraffic in your android manifest

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```